# Minimizing multiple if else conditions in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, if-statement

I have this method in cakephp controller. Here I try to save the user subscription data to the subscription table based on whether the user is already registered to the site or not. I have two form fields named `Name` and `Email`. So if a user is logged in and clicks on the subscribe button, the form pop-up comes up with his name and e-mail already filled in the boxes and if he submits it, he will be subscribed. When a user who is not registered and not logged in, but just want to subscribe, he will have an empty subscription form to fill.

Later I added some modifications that if any user, registered or not registered, wants to subscribe with the same e-mail, a pop-up will show saying: "you are already registered". So far I have done this. It works okay but with a lot of if and else conditions. Any idea about how to minimize this will be helpful. I am new to cakephp and all these things. My controller method code is below:

```
    function subscription_add() {       
        if(!empty($this->data)){            
            if($this->Session->check('User')){
                $is_subscribed = $this->Subscription->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('Subscription.email' => $this->data['Subscription']['email'])));          
                    if($is_subscribed > 0){
                        $this->Session->setFlash('You are already Subscribed !','default',array(),'E');
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->data['Subscription']['user_type'] = 1;
                        $this->data['Subscription']['user_id'] = $this->Session->read('User.id');
                        $this->Subscription->create();
                    if ($this->Subscription->save($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Congrats ! You are Subscribed ', 'default', array(), 'S');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('You are not subscribed. Please, try again.', 'default',array(),'E');
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $subscribed = $this->Subscription->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('Subscription.email' => $this->data['Subscription']['email'])));     
                    if($subscribed > 0){
                        $this->Session->setFlash('You are already Subscribed !','default',array(),'E');
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    }else{
                     $this->Subscription->create();                    
                    if ($this->Subscription->save($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Congrats ! You are Subscribed ', 'default', array(), 'S');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('You are not subscribed.. Please, try again.', 'default',array(),'E');
                        } 
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use Model validation on the email field to check if someone is already registered. No need for half of that code as the framework takes care of it for you.

[Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-new-validation-rules)

Comment: Thanx Friend for suggesting.But i want to if it can be done through coding.It will be of great help if you help me on this. @mcgowan.b

Comment: You could call the find method once and store the result in a variable that you can use instead of calling find multiple times..........